# Display Php (json) output in tabular format

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to Wordpress Plugin Developement,Wrote a function that requests a url for data and gets the same in Json Format,The Function Snippet is as follows;

```
function user_det()
{
$em = '';
$url = ''.$em;
$myhtml = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get($url, array( 'timeout'=>120)));
echo '<pre>' , print_r($myhtml) , '</pre>';
}
```

The Output:

```
{

"Status":"Success",
"Bookings":[
    {
        "Message":"",
        "Detail":{
            "ServiceType":"",
            "HoName":"",
            "HAddress1":"",
            "ToRooms":"",
            "RoDetail":[
                {
                    "RoomTypeDescription":[
                        " "
                    ],
                    "NumberOfRooms":"",
                    "Passengers":[
                        {
                            "Salutations":"",
                            "FirstName":"",
                            "LastName":""                         
                        },
                        {
                            "Salutations":"",

                            "Age":"",
                            "CotBedOption":""
                        }
                    ],
                    "totalAdult":2,
                    "totalChild":0
                }
            ],
            "Phone":"-",
            "Rating":"",
            "email":""
        }
    }]}
```

However ,Is there a way where I could Display the data in a tabular format,tried searching online but could not understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are getting the information in JSON format from your API request, you'll need to iterate each element to format the way you want, example of building a table using this information.

```
$myhtml = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get($url, array( 'timeout'=>120)));
$dataArray = json_decode($myhtml,1);
echo '<table>';
echo '<thead><tr><th>Service Type</th></tr></thead>';
echo '<tbody>';
// Now we have the json converted into an array, let's iterate it
foreach($dataArray["Bookings"] as $idx=>$bookingData) {
    // Iterate all bookings and write on the rows
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$bookingData['Detail']['ServiceType'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody><table>';
```

I believe this gives you the idea on what you need to perform to get your object and build a table.

Comment: Don't understand the use of this line : "$idx=>$bookingData"

Comment: When you iterate an array using foreach, you can access the array index ($idx) and the value ($bookingData). On this case you could only have foreach($dataArray["Bookings"] as $bookingData) , as we don't need the array index.

Comment: Got It ,Thanks.